# I applied a background of linear gradient ,it should start from red and reveal the blue as i scroll but the gradient is fixed to its position

Tags: html, css

How do I apply a linear gradient that stretches to the bottom of the `div` so that when I scroll to the bottom different colors are revealed?

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  background: linear-gradient(red, blue);
}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sed dolor lerisque massa laoreet at. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec euismod augue nibh, ac bibendum tellus tempor nec. Vestibulum anteante.alesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec euismod augue nibh, ac bibendum tellus tempor nec. Vestibulum anteante.
e nibh, ac bibendum tellus temp
e nibh, ac bibendum tellus tempor nec. Vestibulum ante
</div>
```

Comment: it's not clear what you want, can you add an illustration?

Comment: imagine u want a div 100x100 px with a linea gradient which has a very long paragraph and u set the overflow to auto so people can scroll down to the 100x100 px div to see content , u want them to see the first color on top of the paragraph and other colors as they scroll...

Answer (score 1):

You can set the [`background-attachment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment) property to `local`

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  background: linear-gradient(red, blue);
  background-attachment: local;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sed dolor lerisque massa laoreet at. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec euismod augue nibh, ac bibendum tellus tempor nec.
  Vestibulum anteante.alesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec euismod augue nibh, ac bibendum tellus tempor nec. Vestibulum anteante. e nibh, ac bibendum tellus temp e nibh, ac bibendum tellus tempor nec. Vestibulum ante
</div>
```

Comment: but if i customise scrollbar of my div the background doesnt flow to scrollbar